# Laravel : Error when using first() back to back on a query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have the following code in my laravel project

```
$config = DB::table('custom_config')->where('item_id', 5);
$cost = [
    'car_service_fee' => $config->where('managed_by', 1)->first()->service_fee,
    'bike_service_fee' => $config->where('managed_by', 2)->first()->service_fee
];
```

My `custom_config` table is as of below.

```
+---------+------------+-------------+
| item_id | managed_by | service_fee |
|---------+------------+-------------|
|    5    |       1    |    8.5      |
|---------+------------+-------------|
|    5    |       2    |    2.0      |
+---------+------------+-------------+
```

my `car_service_fee` is fetching the result of `8.5`

but my `bike_service_fee` is returning `null` on `first()`

The same code works if it is just like given below,

```
$cost = [
    'car_service_fee' => DB::table('custom_config')->where('item_id', 5)->where('managed_by', 1)->first()->service_fee,
    'bike_service_fee' => DB::table('custom_config')->where('item_id', 5)->where('managed_by', 2)->first()->service_fee
];
```

Is there any problem on back to back `first()` method used on a query builder that is stored in a variable or something in laravel?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$config` is a Query Builder object. The majority of calls you are making on this object are 'building' a query. The object keeps all these `where` conditions internally. When a method to execute the query is called it will compile the query, execute it and return a result [calling `first` or `get` or ...]. The builder itself still exists as a builder and can continue to be built upon or the query can be executed again, etc.

In your case you are adding more `where` conditions to this single query object, `$config`, every time you call `where` on it.

You can see this behavior at any time by calling `toSql` on a builder to see what the generated query would look like.

You can avoid this by creating a new builder object or cloning `$config` so you can have 2 separate queries being built.

Example:

```
$config = DB::table('custom_config')->where('item_id', 5);
$config2 = clone $config;

$cost = [
     'car_service_fee' => $config->where('managed_by', 1)->first()->service_fee,
     'bike_service_fee' => $config2->where('managed_by', 2)->first()->service_fee
];
```

`$config` and `$config2` both have the first `where` condition.

You could just clone them inline as well, if you don't need these builders after the fact:

```
'car_service_fee' => (clone $config)->where(...)->first()->...,
'bike_service_fee' => (clone $config)->where(...)->first()->...,
```

Answer (score 0):

each time you call `where()` function on the `$config` object make a new copy on it and then call the function

```
$cost = [
     'car_service_fee' => (clone $config)->where('managed_by', 1)->first()->service_fee,
     'bike_service_fee' => (clone $config)->where('managed_by', 2)->first()->service_fee
];
```